# Convert Spring Roo Application into a JBoss 6 Application

Tags: java, spring, jboss, spring-roo

I have a Spring Roo app that is deploying to Tomcat with no issues. I'm trying to deploy it to JBoss 6, but I'm finding it impossible to do so.

I've exhausted all resources from Google and I simply receive errors everywhere. Unfortunately, they do not seem specific enough to start narrowing them down to list here.

What can information could I provide to help resolve this situation?

Essentially, I need to know what I need to change from a standard Spring Roo app, using Hibernate and Mysql to work with JBoss 6.

EDIT:

This is the error that I am getting

```
[ClassLoaderManager] Unexpected error during load of:org.apache.commons.collections.DoubleOrderedMap$1$1: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.apache.commons.collections.DoubleOrderedMap$1$1 cannot access its superclass org.apache.commons.collections.DoubleOrderedMap$DoubleOrderedMapIterator
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impossible to tell, since you posted no errors.

I'm guessing that it's a problem with the configuration difference between JBOSS and Tomcat.

You set up JDBC data source connection pools differently.  Tomcat has the context.xml in the server /conf folder.  JBOSS has other XML config files in its server/default/deploy folder.  Did you create those correctly?

I assume that you're using JNDI names for injected data sources.

Your JDBC driver JAR for MySQL goes in the Tomcat /lib folder and the JBOSS server/default/deploy/lib folder, not the wAR WEB-INF/lib.

But you should be able to take a WAR with all the Spring Roo stuff, put it into an EAR with jboss-web.xml configuration, and start it up.

Comment: Hmm, for some reason my JBoss 6 home directory does not have the server directory. It does have standalone/deployments though...

Comment: I'm looking at my JBOSS 5.1.2 directory structure.  I don't know if it's changed for version 6.

Comment: I reinstalled JBoss 6 and now I have the correct server. Strange. Unfortunately still having an issue, I'll try to dig up the error to post here.

Comment: The directory structure matches what you original posted. I have the "server" directory now, before I did not.

Comment: That might explain why you couldn't get JBOSS to work more than a Roo problem.